# Is there a way I can check if a function is true inside another function?

Tags: php

Is there a way I can check if a function is true inside another function?

For example.

```
function Name() {
    //check database
}

function Send() {
    if(Name() == TRUE){
        //do something
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean, check if a function 'is' true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure: just make sure the function returns `TRUE`:

```
function Name() {
  echo 'Some Name';

  return TRUE;
}

function Send() {
  if (Name() == TRUE) {
    // Do something
  }
}
```

Comment: do I add  return TRUE; at the end of the function

Comment: You return TRUE when you want to leave the function and return the value TRUE: in this case, it's at the end, but in other cases it might be somewhere else or not at all (for example, if you start adding logic to your function).

Comment: the Return will exit and return the value out of the function, so you return true at the point which the function has been proven true, or false for that matter

Answer (score 0):

*Edit: What `Mark Trapp` said. ;)

That should work. You would just need to `return true;` or `return false;` in the `Name()` function and you should be set.

Comment: If you're removing your answer by editing, then you might as well delete the answer.